# ¿Qué quiere decir "comer la oreja" a alguien?

Tags: definiciones, diferencias-regionales, expresiones

En conversaciones coloquiales se oye con frecuencia la expresión "comer la oreja" a alguien.

¿Cuál es su significado exacto? Yo la entiendo en el castellano de España como "intentar seducir a alguien", pues al fin y al cabo el acto de hablar a alguien muy cerca de la oreja suele tener esa finalidad.

¿Tiene alguna otra connotación en otros países de habla castellana?

Comment: Nótese que también me recuerda la [mordida de oreja de Mike Tyson a Evander Holyfield](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/02/18/article-0-0004001500000258-730_634x429.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

El significado realmente no es "intentar *seducir* a alguien", sino "**convencer** a alguien de algo" (aunque se puede argumentar que eso también puede ser considerado *seducir* a alguien), hablándole con insistencia, con zalamerías, etc.

Aparte de una posible interpretación casi literal (que tendría las connotaciones de *lamer* o *morder* la oreja en un sentido "íntimo") no parece tener diferentes significados en base a diferencias regionales.

Comment: comer la oreja = comer el oído? Encontré la segunda expresión en la letra de la canción "Chantaje" de Shakira.

Answer (score 7):

Yo lo he oído más con el significado de *insistir majaderamente, tratando que el otro acepte por cansancio*. Soy chileno y acá no se usa casi nunca, pero lo he escuchado en películas.

Answer (score 5):

Yo siempre lo usé con el significado de:

> comer el coco [a alguien], comer la cabeza [a alguien]

**comerle la oreja** sería lo mismo pero sin ser tan evidente que el receptor ha asimilado el discurso (aún no llegó tan hondo de comerle la cabeza, aún anda por la oreja). Hace más referencia a lo pesado que es uno respecto al otro para convencerlo de algo, como una mosca cojonera.

> Sugestionar por insistencia verbal [a alguien] para que adquiera una opinión determinada

Answer (score 2):

Hace referencia a que "susurrar" y "comer" tienen gestos bucales similares.

`Comerle la oreja a alguien` significa `tratar de convencerlo, de forma insistente`, pero yo añadiría que es de forma sutil.

"Comer la oreja" no es convencer con un debate de ideas, sino que más bien es tratar de llevártelo poco a poco adonde tú quieres; es *sembrar dudas* en el otro, hasta que poco a poco se empieza a convencer de lo que tú dices.

Por eso, creo que los "susurros continuos" son la conexión entre la expresión y su significado.

Comment: Creo que este significado lleva algo en parentesco con la expresión en México que es *lavar(le) el coco (a alguien)*.

Answer (score 1):

En México una forma equivalente de dicha expresión, es **endulzarle el oído** que hace referencia a intentar tener influencia en una persona para que haga o diga determinadas cosas, teniendo como base escuchar de alguien más lo que ella/el mismo deseaba oír.

Es decir influir en las elecciones y decisiones de una persona, teniendo como base decirle cosas que lo harían ser susceptible de actuar como deseamos.

Ejemplos.

- *Eres muy bueno para ese trabajo si yo fuera tu me iría a otro lado* esto equivaldría a tratar de hacer que una persona renuncie a su puesto actual pero sin ser directos para que el resultado final de dicha influencia se le pueda asignar directamente a quien toma la elección de renunciar
- *No asistas a clases no importa, mejor quédate a ver televisión haces mas falta aquí o ¿quieres perder el tiempo?* El resultado dará a alguien que no asiste por que es influenciado/influenciada por alguien mas

Punto final.

La idea es influir en la toma decisiones de alguien más, pero que sea de una forma sutil y los resultados se vean como una elección propia y no como consecuencia de conducir a alguien a dicho resultado

Answer (score 0):

En Uruguay significa atomizarlo. Para que sea más fácil de entender, una moto que haga mucho ruido te puede comer la oreja, una persona que habla con insistencia te puede comer la oreja. 
Para expresarle a una que está comiendo oreja le podés decir: "pah, me estás comiendo oreja","¡Que loco come oreja", etc

Comment: "En Uruguay significa **atomizarlo**" Quienes no conozcan este término no entenderán la definición. Deberías poner un poco más de esfuerzo en explicar lo que se se está queriendo expresar. "una moto que haga mucho ruido te puede comer la oreja," Quiere esto decir que te castiga o molesta la oreja?